# Ajax Post method not working for user defined function

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

`UpdateModule` is a function used for update module details. It's not a view page.

When click on update, it returns 500 (internal server error) or  404 error

please help to fix it

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("ETM_PRODUCTS","UpdateModule")',

        //contentType: 'application/json',
        datatype: JSON,

        data: { 'ModuleID': ModuleID, 'ModuleName': ModuleName, 'ModuleDescription': ModuleDescription },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == true) {
                alert("Updated Successfully");
            }
        },
        error: function (msg) {
             alert("Error")
        },
    });
```

c#

```
public JsonResult UpdateModule(int ModuleID,string ModuleName,string ModuleDescription) {
        bool status = true;
       PROD_MODULE tabledata = db.PROD_MODULE.Where(x => x.ETM_MODULE_ID == ModuleID)
                           .FirstOrDefault();

        tabledata.NAME = ModuleName;
        tabledata.DESCRIPTION = ModuleDescription;
                           db.SaveChanges();

        return Json ( status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
    }
```

Comment: check the console in your browser's devtools. It would usually tell you if your ajax request fails. Also try logging the error returned from server
instead of
    alert("Error");
try
    console.log(msg);
or
    console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));

Comment: You need to provide more info, like Update button clicking handler code, etc. Also please check the console to see if it goes to correct Requested URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in the way you call `Url.Action`.

The first parameter is the action and the second the controller.

Here is the documentation : [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758(v=vs.118).aspx)